# Fetching Assets using Asset resource failing with error "null"

Tags: ios, phasset, phassetcollection, phassetslibrary

My application reads photos and videos available in Camera Roll, using `PHAssetResource` application is fetching the original photo and video data. Below is the code used to retrieve the data from Camera Roll.

```
for (PHAssetResource *resource in copyResources)
{
PHAssetResourceRequestOptions *options = [PHAssetResourceRequestOptions new];
options.networkAccessAllowed = allowCloud;
PHAssetResourceDataRequestID requestID = [[PHAssetResourceManager defaultManager] requestDataForAssetResource:resource options:options dataReceivedHandler:^(NSData *data) {} completionHandler:^(NSError *requestError) {}

}
```

Sometimes original asset fetch is getting failed,and completion handler gets called with error

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-1 "(null)"

I have no info why this is failing. Can you please provide some suggestions to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this happens for photos/videos only in iCloud and not being on the device itself. The best approach would be to retry the request as the underlying issue is an iCloud server error.